# Declare test wrapping other tests in Spock

Tags: testing, junit, spock

In my app I have some use cases I want to integration test. The use cases are cross cut using aspects to send metrics to another system. Normally I would write a test which will test the use case behavior and then pull the metrics and do some asserts on them. However, I don't want to mix verifying use cases and metrics in one test. I also don't want to duplicate use case test code just to verify the metrics.

I was thinking about the solution which will allow me to somehow declare that metrics tests should be run right after corresponding use case test (somehow wrapping or mixing with it). Use case tests shouln't depend on metrics tests. Is is possible with Spock/Junit?

Answer (score 0):

> Normally I would write a test which will test the use case behavior
>   and then pull the metrics and do some asserts on them

Normally you should write a test that tests just the use case and nothing else. 
Write different tests for your metrics.

If you really really want to write integration tests that test both the use cases and the metrics then that is the way to go (i.e a single test that tests both)

In fact, you should only write tests for things you have created yourself. If your metrics are an external library that you just use, there is no need to write tests for them.

Comment: Since it's a integration test, I want to make sure, that my app is correctly integrating with metrics service. It doesn't matter that I am using external library.
About different tests for metrics - different use cases are generating different metrics, I need to execute the same code there is in use case test, I just want to skip the duplication.

Comment: Why the duplication? Just create a parent class that all your unit tests extend and reuse its functionality.

Comment: Also if you want to test both the use case and the metric then a single integration test for both is the way to go.